# IOS 4.2: Access data (contacts, messages, etc)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Is there a way to programmatically access and modify the core data of the iphone?

I'm making an app for myself, not for the apple store, and I want to be able to access my list of contacts (to delete it) and the list of messages (also to delete it).

I want to make an application with the same behaviour has that feature which allows you to block the iphone in case of theft.

It's being hard to find information about this so any help would be nice :)

/thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a particularly helpful answer, because it implies ABAddressBook is going to give you all of the information you want (it isn't). ABAddressBook *will* give you access to contacts. It *won't* give you access to messages. Access to SMS and email messages isn't available to developers, for various reasons (privacy, security, etc). So you won't be able to do anything with users messages, because you don't have access to them.

Answer (score 2):

For contact info, use [ABAddressBook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html)